# laravel checkbox как получить 1 или 0

Tags: php, laravel

Blade

```
<form action="{{route('question-store')}}" method="post">
    @csrf
    <div>
        <label for="question">Title</label>
        <input type="text" id="question" name="question">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="position">Position</label>
        <input type="text" id="position" name="position">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="is_show">Show</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="is_show" value="1" name="is_show" checked="checked">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Create">
</form>
```

Request

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'question'    =>  'required|min:5',
        'is_show'     =>  'boolean',
        'position'    =>  'required|numeric',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Поясните подробнее, пожалуйста

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<div>
    <label for="is_show">Show</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="is_show" value="0" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="is_show" value="1" name="is_show" checked="checked">
</div>
```